# Magento 2 Custom shipping Carrier module

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am sort of new to magento 2, I have to add custom shipping carrier using an API which gives multiple options based on product dimensions.

using http://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/
I was able to get it in. the only issue is that I am supposed to have multiple methods or options for users to select.

I was able to add multiple methods by doing something like below

```
 for ($n = 0; $n < count($optionz); $n++) {
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create(); 
        $method->setMethod($this->_code."_".$n);
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($optionz[$n]['service']);
        $method->setCost($optionz[$n]['fee']);
        $method->setPrice($optionz[$n]['fee']);
        $result->append($method);
    }
```

but once I select the option from checkout page and click next I get below:

"Carrier with such method not found: %1, %2"

any ideas? thanks in advance :).

Kind Regards
Sajid

Comment: You can check below link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14695/how-to-add-shipping-method-options Hope that helps!

Comment: thats exactly what I did exactly same as you see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you must be facing selection issue in js, try to append unique id for each. That should solve the issue.

Comment: I think unique ID is this "setMethod($this->_code."_".$n)" part right? (and I can see them in js part as well) I am able to select an option but as soon as I client on next button i get following:

{"message":"Carrier with such method not found: %1, %2","parameters":["myshipping","myshipping_express"]}

Comment: Can you please help? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250968/vnecoms-vendor-flate-rate-shipping-carrier-with-such-method-not-found-vflatrate

Comment: The solution is to set a method unique code name,  i.e:

**setMethod("method_one")**

**setMethod("method_two")**